# How to get SCNTransaction end

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, scenekit, skspritenode

I have a SKSpriteNode I use like a button. 
When I tap on it, it calls a function that moves the camera in a SCNScene

```
 SCNTransaction.begin()
 SCNTransaction.setAnimationDuration(2)

 SCNTransaction.setCompletionBlock {
        SCNTransaction.begin()
        SCNTransaction.setAnimationDuration(2)

        self.ResetCameraButton.texture = self.FunctionAtlas.textureNamed("ResetCameraSelected")

        self.cameraOrbit.eulerAngles.y = initialAngleY
        self.cameraOrbit.eulerAngles.x = initialAngleX
        self.cameraNode.camera?.orthographicScale = self.initialPinchScale

        SCNTransaction.commit()

            }
 SCNTransaction.commit()
```

This is the button: [image] and this is the tapped button: [image]

I would like to put the second image, as texture of my SKSpriteNode, **during the animation** and the first one, only when the **animation ends**.

If I add below:

> self.ResetCameraButton.texture = self.FunctionAtlas.textureNamed("ResetCameraUnselected")

to set the *Unselected* texture, it doesn't work!

How can I get the end of the animation to set the 'unselected' texture to my SKSpriteNode?

Answer (score 1):

`SKNode`s are part of SpriteKit which does not understand `SCNTransaction`. Only SceneKit APIs marked as "animatable" in the documentation can benefit from this feature.

Comment: Ok, but how can I get that effect?

Answer (score 0):

Check the [documentation for SKAction](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skaction).